# Run Script Terminal Commands Orderly

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, terminal, unix, code

how do i run the script below orderly ? (execute task after 1 task is done)

```
Code 1

    for i in *.mp4;
      do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
      echo "$name"
      ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -i "$i" "${name}.ts”

wait

Code 2

    mkdir new
    
    for file in *.ts ; do
        ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -i "concat:intro.ts|${file}" -c copy "new/${file}"

wait

Code 3

    cd /Users/Blabla/Movies/Learn/new

wait

Code4

    for i in *.ts;
      do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
      echo "$name"
      ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -i "$i" "${name}.mp4” 

done
```

Thanks Much Appreciated

edit 1:
i'm new to coding and ffmpeg, and i want to process the first file to the end (all steps) and only then move to the next file

Comment: Answered here [bash - Wait for a process to finish - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-a-process-to-finish/11719943)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Almost all your `for` loops miss `done`, you seem to use `wait` instead. `wait` is a builtin to wait for a child process of the shell. You're running nothing asynchronously, so `wait` makes no sense here. If you fix the loops and run them in sequence, the steps will run in order, not in parallel. Or do you want to process the first file to the end (all steps) and only then move to the next file? Then you need exactly one loop. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski i'm new to coding and ffmpeg, and yes i want to process the first file to the end (all steps) and only then move to the next file